# Using Conditional Formatting, highlight a cells based on value in adjacent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

How to highlight column B values based on corresponding Column A value using conditional formatting.

Thanks in advance

NRM

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Create your conditional format rule.

Open the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager 

Show formatting rules for:  This Worksheet 

Click on the line for the rule to select it.

Enter `=$B$1:$B$999` (or the end of your data or even `=$B:$B`) in the Applies To box.

Click OK.

This will apply the rule you entered to the column B.